# if/elif questions not working?

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and preparing to start it as a GCSE. I have been trying to do a capital of France question set in school with different responses for some answers, but it has not been working. The syntax error 'unindent does not match any outer indentation level' comes up after the response for when answers are incorrect (e.g. after print('Right Country, Wrong City. Try again.'). Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
print('What is the capital of France?')
answer==input('Enter your answer:')
if answer == 'Paris':
    print('Well Done! That\'s Correct.')
 elif answer == 'Lyon':
     print('Right country, Wrong city. Try again.')
     input('Enter your answer:')
 elif answer == 'F':
    print('Terrible joke and the wrong answer. Try again.')
    input('Enter your answer:')
 else:
    print('Sorry, that\'s incorrect. Try again.')
    input('Enter your answer:')
```

Comment: elif should be on the same level as that of if

Comment: `=` is for affectation, `==` is for comparaison.  change `answer==input('Enter your answer:')` to `answer=input('Enter your answer:')`

Comment: Also, if your answer is incorrect, you probably want jump back to the second line instead of using another input() statement. A `while` loop would be suitable for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the previous answers, I just wanted to point out that it is better to use a while loop and assign the value to 'answer' within the while loop. This way, you can also insert a 'break' statement, that will terminate the program once you digit the word 'exit' or provide the right answer. Here is the code:

```
print('What is the capital of France?')
while True:
    answer=input('Enter your answer, or type "exit" to close the program: ')  
    if answer=='exit':
        print('Program terminated')
        break 
    elif answer == 'Paris':
        print('Well Done! That\'s Correct.')
        break
    elif answer == 'Lyon':
         print('Right country, Wrong city. Try again.')
    elif answer == 'F':
        print('Terrible joke and the wrong answer. Try again.')
    else:
        print('Sorry, that\'s incorrect. Try again.')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation was off in the if/elif/else block

If you're assigning a variable, it should be one `=` not `==`

If you want to prompt for the correct answer again, you have to reassign the variable `answer` (`answer = input(....)`)

Also you may want to run a `while answer == 'Paris'` or something similar so that way it prompts continuously until the answer is the value you want it to be

```
print('What is the capital of France?')
answer = input('Enter your answer:')
if answer == 'Paris':
    print('Well Done! That\'s Correct.')
elif answer == 'Lyon':
    print('Right country, Wrong city. Try again.')
    input('Enter your answer:')
elif answer == 'F':
    print('Terrible joke and the wrong answer. Try again.')
    input('Enter your answer:')
else:
    print('Sorry, that\'s incorrect. Try again.')
    input('Enter your answer:')
```

Answer (score 0):

At first when you want to save something in variable, you just use one = not == of them

At second you need to have all elif and if on same place dont use tabulators python is very sensitive on this

And for the answer you need to do loop maybe while to repeat until they write the right question

Answer (score -1):

You should not use input(), but instead use raw_input().

Comment: This is a Python3 v Python2 difference...if OP is using Python3 this answer is void